# How to acess has_many_through file urls of file uploaded using carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.0

How can I access the url of the file which is present in the related model and uploaded by using carrier wave.
I have three Models like:

```
class ThreeDModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :three_d_model_animations
  has_many :animations, through: :three_d_model_animations
end
```

2nd

```
class Animation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :three_d_model_animations
  has_many :three_d_models, through: :three_d_model_animations
  mount_uploader :video, AnimationVideoUploader
  validates_presence_of :video
end
```

3rd

```
class ThreeDModelAnimation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :animation
  belongs_to :three_d_model
  validates_presence_of :animation_file
  mount_uploader :animation_file, ThreeDModelAnimationUploader
end
```

so, now I want to access the url of the video which is present in the Animation model uploaded using carrier wave,along with the fields in the ThreeDModelAnimation and url of the aimation file.
Because if go with the joins and select query the url to the files will be lost. please tell me how to acheive it without loosing the file_url to the file.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you want to access the `URL` of the video from?

Comment: through the ThreeDModelAnimation class objects

Comment: To be honest I don't completely understand what you want to achieve here. Since you want an object of `ThreeDModelAnimation` to access the animation it's linked to you can just to `ThreeDModelAnimation.first.animation`, I am considering that the object is the first object of `ThreeDModelAnimation`.